# How to add 1000x1000px white background to photos in bulk?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photo-editing, automation

I have about 650 photos, I want to add a white background to them so that the photos' height doesn't exceed 1000px, see an example below.

This is the white background:
[image: there's a white image here]

It's a photoshop file that I saved it as .jpg, and this is the photo that will be put on it:

[image]

So in the end, it'd look like this, a 1000x1000 px photo:

[image]

PS: Please drag the files out in the browser so you could see the background difference since it's white.

PSS: Preferably Photoshop/Illustrator/GraphicsMagick/Node.js.

Answer (score 5):

You need to [record an action](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) that would simply take your batch of images and:

1. scale the height of the images to 8-900px or similar, assuming you need some white space around the products instead of them going all the way to the edge
2. duplicate this step for the width to be also scaled to 8-900px in images that remain over 1000px wide after step 1
3. make sure the background color is set to white in Photoshop
4. adjust the canvas size to 1000x1000px

Save the action and run it on your folder with images via 'File → Scripts → Image Processor → Preferences → Run Action'.